# How to filter inside only certain groups (that satisfy a particular condition) in grouped tibble, using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using mtcars dataset, as an example. I would like to:

1. group table based on the number of cylinders
2. within each group test whether any car has miles per gallon higher than 25 ( mpg > 25)
3. for only those groups that have at least one car with mpg > 25, I would like to remove the cars that have mpg < 20

The expected output is cars that belong to a cylinder group with at least one other car having mpg > 25, and that themselves have mpg < 20 are removed from dataset

PS: I can think of several ways to address this problem, but I wanted to see if someone can come up with straightforward and elegant solution, e.g.

```
xx <- split (mtcars, f = mtcars$cyl)
for (i in seq_along (xx)){
  if (any (xx[[i]]$mpg) > 25) xx[[i]] <- filter (xx[[i]] > 20)
}
xx <- bind_rows (xx)
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? What is the expected output?

Comment: added the expected output. I can of course solve this issue on my own, by doing a bunch of things, e.g. splitting the tibble into a list, or adding a "remove_car" column that says TRUE, FALSE, then ungrouping, filtering on it and removing this column. But my question is what is the elegant solution to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(if(any(mpg > 25)) mpg > 20 else TRUE) %>%
  ungroup

#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
# 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
# 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
# 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

From the groups which has at least one value greater than 25 in `mpg`, we keep only the rows that has values greater than 20. If a group has no value greater than 25 keep all the rows of those groups.

Comment: I do not understand the syntax inside filter(), could you elaborate, if you have time?

Comment: this removed the whole group where cyl == 6, so this doesn't work

Comment: added R code that generates expected output

Comment: I think if you change `FALSE` to `TRUE` in my code it should work that defines what to do when there is no value `> 25`. Previously, I was removing those groups, using `TRUE` would keep all the rows of that group.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(any(mpg > 25) & mpg > 20) %>%
  ungroup
```